# In C++, what is the best way to do conversions of similar classes between libraries?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, libraries

I happen to be working on a project that uses the `glm` and `Box2D` libraries. Both of these include implementations of, for example, a 2D vector. Sometimes, I'll need to convert values from one library's format to another. I can't just write the appropriate constructors in the classes because that would involve modification of the library source code, which is a bad idea for many reasons.

Now, the obvious solution is just to write some utility functions that convert one to another, eg. `convertVec2()`. This would work. However, it's a bit clunky and verbose, and I can't help but wonder if there's some cleverer way of doing it, possibly using some cunning use of obscure language functionality.

Is there a better way to solve the problem? Or should I just do the boring and straightforward thing?

Comment: "Now, the obvious solution is just to write some utility functions that convert one to another, eg. convertVec2()." - Yeah, You pretty much have to do that. There are no clever shortcuts if you cannot modify the libraries. You have to transform one type to another and the code to do that has to go *somewhere* - a utility function is quite reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the obvious solution is just to write some utility functions that convert one to another

> should I just do the boring and straightforward thing?

Yes, this is a decent approach.

Note that in special case of the types being layout compatible, you can simply reinterpret a pointer to one as being a pointer to the other type.

In short, types are layout compatible if they are either the same type, or both are standard layout classes and all members of each class are layout compatible with the corresponding member of the other class. For example, following classes are layout compatible:

```
struct Vec2D {
    float x, y;
};


struct Point {
    float X, Y;
};
```

Since C++20 you can test that with the type trait `std::is_layout_compatible`.

Comment: Very good point, but as a developer, I'd be wary of depending on layout compatibility. Any upgrade of either library could break my code. It can pay off in performance in the immediate, but It's not the most future-proof.

Comment: @Jeffrey That's why `std::is_layout_compatible` is so important. The added complexity of handling both compatible and incompatible cases can sometimes be worth it for performance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no better way.

And this is not a shortcoming. It's actually a feature. Both libraries have picked an API they found usable for you but also maintainable for *them*. One reason to encapsulate features is to allow the developers to make change without breaking your code.

So, next week, `glm` might decide to store 3D vectors as `std::string`s internally. It would be a bad decision, but they could, as long as they maintain the public API. Similarly, `Box2D` might decide to have a global store of copy-on-write 3D vectors. Also a dubious idea, but still, their choice. As long as they maintain the API, you would be able to have your code working.

Now imagine you came up with your own fast conversion. Do you really expect it to still work once both implementations change as above? Nope.

The price you pay for having a stable API and for the developers to be able to maintain their stuff is that you don't get fast copy/conversion.